# Laravel sort child relationship collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following 3 tables:
**Movie**
- id
**Series**
- id
- status_id
- movie_id
**Status**
- id
- order_number

this is the code on the controller:

```
$movie = Movie::where('slug', $slug)->with(['series'])->first();
```

this is the code for view:

```
@foreach ($movie->series as $series)
  {{ $series->name}}
@endforeach
```

how to sort `$movie->series` based on `status->order_number`? if it can be written on the model, so every order is only written once the controller?

is there a code that I can use for example like this:

```
$movie->series->sortBy('status.order_number');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you will need to join status with series:

```
$movie = Movie::where('slug', $slug)->with([
    'series' => function ($query) {
        // Subquery on `series` table
        return $query
            // select whatever you'll need
            ->select('series.*')
            // join with status
            ->join('status', 'series.status_id', '=', 'status.id')
            // order by order number
            ->orderBy('status.order_number')
            // * you can drop this if you select all the fields you need and use those
            ->with('status');
    },
])->first();
```

**Edit** this ^ method will sort on SQL level, but you could also do this with collections:

```
@foreach ($movie->series->sortBy('status.order_number') as $series)
  {{ $series->name}}
@endforeach
```

In that case also add `.status` to your `with` to avoid n + 1 problem: `->with(['series.status'])`

The reason your attempt didn't work is because `->sortBy(..)` doesn't mutate the collection, it just returns a new sorted one. This would work:

```
$movie->series = $movie->series->sortBy('status.order_number');
```